# Why Sqlite3 table wont UPDATE

Tags: python, sqlite

I've tried making an update to my sqlite3 table but it doesn't seem to work.

```
marks = "My long name here"
conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute("UPDATE '" + str(marks) +"' SET (ENG,KIS,MAT,BIO) = (-1,-1,-1,-1) WHERE (ENG,KIS,MAT,BIO) =('nan','nan','nan','nan')")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I can't see nay error in my code.

Comment: Convert the `update` query into `Select` query and check if your Python code is able to communicate with the `sqlite` db and is also able to find records for the condition you specified in `Where`.

Comment: Let me try it.I'll give feedback

Comment: It could be a case where the Update statement ran fine, but could not find any records to update due to `WHERE` condition not yielding anything. Hence no error.

Comment: And what could cause the WHERE not to yield anything? I have it in the statement

Comment: Basically what I mean is, the condition you are checking in the `where` clause might not be matching any records from the table. If that is the case, you might want to tweak your where.

Comment: @Mayank, I've just realized that the code could not work when combined like that. I've had to separate it so that each item is worked on separately.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need 4 separate statements.
You can do it in 1 statement with `CASE` expressions:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET ENG = CASE WHEN ENG = 'nan' THEN -1 ELSE ENG END, 
    KIS = CASE WHEN KIS = 'nan' THEN -1 ELSE KIS END,
    MAT = CASE WHEN MAT = 'nan' THEN -1 ELSE MAT END,
    BIO = CASE WHEN BIO = 'nan' THEN -1 ELSE BIO END
WHERE 'nan' IN (ENG,KIS,MAT,BIO)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked, separating them.

```
marks = "My long name here"
conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute("UPDATE '" + str(marks) + "' SET ENG=-1 WHERE ENG='nan'")
cur.execute("UPDATE '" + str(marks) + "' SET KIS=-1 WHERE KIS='nan'")
cur.execute("UPDATE '" + str(marks) + "' SET MAT=-1 WHERE MAT='nan'")
cur.execute("UPDATE '" + str(marks) + "' SET BIO=-1 WHERE BIO='nan'")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Rather than this.

```
marks = "My long name here"
conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute("UPDATE '" + str(marks) +"' SET (ENG,KIS,MAT,BIO) = (-1,-1,-1,-1) WHERE (ENG,KIS,MAT,BIO) =('nan','nan','nan','nan')")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```